# Can't change border colour of switch inside tableview's cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I've a switch inside table which I'm creating programmatically. I can't change switch's off border colour to gray. I tried tint colour which isn't working either.

How to fix it?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell else {
        fatalError("...")
    }
    
    //...        
    let switchView = UISwitch()
    switchView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greyColour.cgColor
            
    cell.accessoryView = switchView
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You say that you can't *change* the border color of a switch, but UISwitches don't have a border color by default. It would be more accurate to say you want to *add* a border color to your switch.

Comment: When you add switch in storyboard it does have everything like default switch. Adding it programatically in a table is not showing the default behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what effect you want to achieve but for `layer.borderColor` to work you need to setup `layer.borderWidth` also. However, because switch layer is rectangular it will look like this:

[image]

Which might be not what you want. So to make the border follow the switcher's shape you'll need to modify its corner radius:

```
switchView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
switchView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
switchView.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
```

to make it looks like this:

[image]

---

Update

If you want to apply border only for switcher off state it'll be a bit more tricky because you need to handle switcher states changes. The easiest way I could think of is to subclass `UISwitch` and provide your own behaviour by overriding `sendActions` method:

```
class BorderedSwitch: UISwitch {
    var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.gray {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
     }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    override var isOn: Bool {
        didSet {
            updateState()
        }
    }

    override func sendActions(for controlEvents: UIControl.Event) {
        super.sendActions(for: controlEvents)
        if controlEvents.contains(.valueChanged) {
            updateState()
        }
    }

    private func setup() {
        layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
        layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    }

    private func updateState() {
        layer.borderWidth = isOn ? 0.0 : 1.0
    }
}
```

Notice that I also updated cornerRadius value to `frame.height / 2` to avoid magic numbers

Comment: I want to make it like default switch colour. With above code It also sets border colour for ON state.

Comment: @Raymond you don't want to set border color for ON state?

Comment: Yes, I want to. I'm not sure why default switch's on/off colour+border is not working? It should work by default, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Raymond I updated the answer to show how to hide border for ON state

Comment: Sorry I didn't say I want to hide border for ON state. I want to show switch with border and colour as it shows for a default switch which you get when you add switch via storyboard.

Comment: @Raymond Sorry, I'm not sure that I understand what you want to achieve. Didn't the initial answer solve your problem? Maybe you could provide a screenshot and specify what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Initial answer for setting border to grey sets border for both ON and OFF state as grey. I want grey for Off and green for ON like you see in a default switch. Check out any switch in Apple's Settings app.

Comment: How about fixing the last func of @ScorpiCon answer to:

private func updateState() {
        layer. borderColor = isOn ? {GREEN}.cgColor : {GRAY}.cgColor // Just put whatever color you want for on and off state.
    }

Comment: @Raymond If you don't see the default behaviour for switch check any changes of general appearance in your code. For example this line of code `UIView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white` will make the switch to show white background regardless of its state.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a switch with code, it looks just like a switch you add in a storyboard. Neither way of creating a switch has a border color.

The code below adds a switch to a view controller's content view:

```
    @IBOutlet var switchView: UISwitch!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        switchView = UISwitch()
        
        switchView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //Remember to do this for UIViews you create in code
        if false {
            //Add a gray border to the switch
            switchView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0  // Draw a rounded rect around the switchView so you can see it
            switchView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            switchView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        }


        //Add it to the container view
        view.addSubview(switchView)

        //Create center x & y layout anchors (with no offset to start)
        let switchViewXAnchor = switchView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0)
        switchViewXAnchor.isActive = true
        
        let switchViewYAnchor =  switchView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor,
                                                             constant: 0.0)
        switchViewYAnchor.isActive = true
    }
```

It looks perfectly normal.